# How to convert json/String to org.w3c.dom.Element object in Java

Tags: java, xml, spring, jackson

`<ns2:Product   xmlns:ns2="urn:http://xy/fzyz-service">     <ns2:searchId>6419e0d870253f55398d26d4</ns2:searchId>   <ns2:travelers>         <ns2:traveler>          <ns2:guest>false</ns2:guest>        </ns2:traveler>     </ns2:travelers>    <ns2:hasInsurance>false</ns2:hasInsurance> </ns2:Product>`

I am getting above Xml in String format & I have to convert it into Element type.

`class  Demo{ Element any; }`

I have tried below code of objectMapper but getting error

`Element element  =  objectMapper.convertValue(aboveXmlInStringFormat,Element.class);`

`Cannot cast 'com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl' to 'org.w3c.dom.Element'`

Answer (score 0):

The String is XML, not JSON. To deserialise it you need to define the target class and use a JAXB unmarshaller as follows:

```
package com.whatever.yahooparser;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;


@XmlRootElement(name = "Product")
@XmlType()
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class ProductModel {
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { //throws JAXBException {
        String input = "<ns2:Product   xmlns:ns2=\"urn:http://xy/fzyz-service\">     <ns2:searchId>6419e0d870253f55398d26d4</ns2:searchId>   <ns2:travelers>         <ns2:traveler>          <ns2:guest>false</ns2:guest>        </ns2:traveler>     </ns2:travelers>    <ns2:hasInsurance>false</ns2:hasInsurance> </ns2:Product>";
            
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ProductModel.class);
        ProductModel productModel = (ProductModel) context.createUnmarshaller()
          .unmarshal(new StringReader(input));
        System.out.println(productModel);
    }
    
    private String searchId;
    private Traveler[] travelers;
    private boolean hasInsurance;

    @XmlElement(name = "searchId")
    public void setSearchId(String searchId) {
        this.searchId = searchId;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "travelers")
    public void setTravelers(Traveler[] travelers) {
        this.travelers = travelers;
    }
    
    @XmlElement(name = "hasInsurance")
    public void setHasInsurance(boolean hasInsurance) {
        this.hasInsurance = hasInsurance;
    }

    @Data
    public static class Traveler {
        
        boolean guest;

        @XmlElement(name = "traveler")
        public void setGuest(boolean guest) {
            this.guest = guest;
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

Output as follows:

```
ProductModel(searchId=6419e0d870253f55398d26d4, travelers=[ProductModel.Traveler(guest=false)], hasInsurance=false)
```

The following are also required.

package-info.java (at package level)

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace="urn:http://xy/fzyz-service",
    elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)  

package com.whatever.yahooparser;

import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
```

Dependencies for JAXB as follows (Java 17+)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.22</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```